# Extracting a directory path or internet path from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

```
string_val = " hello all this is my string here D:\my\Dir\path\is_this thank you for the link "
```

How can i extract "D:\my\Dir\path\is_this" this value from the "string_val".
D can be any drive... like w, q, s, t, r, any ip or xyz.com or file:\\xyz.abcd.in or file:\\123.456.345.233\\filepath

path can be like tis too = D:\\my\\Dir\\path\\is_this

Comment: Why should `' thank you for the link'` be excluded? Spaces are valid in file and directory names.

Comment: Right, you could in principle write a simple regular expression that parses Windows paths, but since spaces are valid parts of a path name you can't know for sure where the path ends.

Comment: i am collecting the value from an excel file where in a cell both string and path will present.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions for this. The following code matches every substring starting with a capital letter followed by ':\' until it hits a whitespace. It wont work if there are whitespaces in your path. (In that case there would be no unique answer to your problem.)

```
import re

string_val = r"hello all this is my string here D:\my\Dir\path\is_this thank you for the link "

matches = re.findall(r'([A-Z]:\\\S+)', string_val)
print(matches[0])

# D:\my\Dir\path\is_this
```

Comment: "D:\my\Dir\path\is this" in this case the output only "D:\my\Dir\path\is" full path is missing

Comment: @KLASR I told you that it wont work if the path contains whitespaces. If you are sure that the text following the path starts with 'thank you', this will work: `matches = re.findall(r'(\w+:\\{1,2}.+?) thank you', string_val)`

Comment: re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]:\\\S.+)', string_val)  worked

Comment: @KLASR No it wont! With the dot between \S and + the regex will match everything till the end of a string. Just check it with your original string. It returns `D:\my\Dir\path\is_this thank you for the link`

Comment: yah... i got that... but actually i having an \n in end of path so... works fine.. but i appreciate your answer.. because of that i got 95% of my work. thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find such strings:

```
found = re.findall(r'\w+\:(?:\\{1,2}\S+)*', string_val)
_ = [print(x) for x in found]
```

This works for `file:\\` as well :)

Comment: "D:\my\Dir\path\is this" this case upto "D:\my\Dir\path\is" here only i am getting... not full path